# Pagination on mongo query inside facet

Tags: mongodb, pagination, aggregate, facet

Im making a change to a query to my collection in mongo and I'm pretty new to writing these robust queries.
For context I have a collection containing sales product documents and regular products.
My goal is to apply all the filtering my query currently handles but now I want to prioritize the sales items to be first in the array of data I am returning from my server.

Non sales products will not have a `salesInfo` field in their documents and sale products will have the field.

So I've added a query to my `$facet` that will retrieve sales documents first under `salesInventoryProducts`.The main difference in the two steps is the `$match` query.

The issue Im running into is understanding how to handle pagination. Previously I just had a `$skip` and a `$limit` query. where `{ $skip: page ? page * pageSize : 0 }` and limit was a simple `pageSize` which = 18.

With the addition of the new step in my facet where I getting all the sales documents first I'm unsure how to handle the skip and limit in the second half of my query since the `inventoryProducts` skip and limit are dependent on the `salesInventoryProducts` count.
Im sure there has to be a way to handle this?

// This is my query with some parts removed for brevity:

```
const pipeline = [
      {$sort: sort,},
      {
        $facet: {
          salesInventoryProducts: [
          {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    salesInfo: { $exists: true }, // Match documents where salesInfo exists
                  },
                  {
                    'salesInfo.salesEndDate': { $gt: currentDate }, // Match documents where salesEndDate is in the future
                  },
                ],
              },
            { $skip: skip }, // skip = page ? page * pageSize : 0;
            { $limit: pageSize }, // pagesize = 18;
            {$lookup: {...},},
            {$set: {...},},
          },
          ],
          inventoryProducts: [
            {
              $match: {
                $and: [
                  { ...query },
                  {
                    $or: [
                      {
                        salesInfo: { $exists: false }, // Match documents where salesInfo doesn't exist
                      },
                      {
                        $or: [
                          { salesInfo: { $exists: true } }, // salesInfo exists
                          { 'salesInfo.salesEndDate': { $lte: currentDate } }, // salesEndDate is in the past
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
            { $skip: }, // some multiple of the page and the number of sales items returned?
            {
              $limit: // what I've tried but errors ... { $subtract: [18, { $size: '$salesInventoryProducts' }] }, // Limit the results based on remaining needed documents
            },
            {$lookup: {...},},
            {$set: {...},},
            },
          ],
          inventoryCount: [{ $count: 'total' }],
        },
      },
    ];
```

The issue Im having is with the skip and limit in the second half of the facet.
But I may run into the same issue in the first half as well.
This may just be a math problem with a little bit of mongo knowledge needed but I'm not sure how to handle this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "_I want to prioritize the sales items to be first in the array of data_" - can you clarify what this means in terms of you schema and/or querying? To me it feels like the straightforward approach here is to factor in your new constraint into the initial sorting of the data thus eliminating the paging complexities afterwards

Comment: I made an update to my question to hopefully clarify things. Please let me know this straightforward approach that I'm missing? In each iteration of this query I have attempted to simplify, I started with these two steps in the facet as separate aggressions and anytime I simplify beyond what I have here like trying a $group for example I end up breaking everything.

Comment: What is your leading `$sort` on?

Comment: My leading sort is a dynamic value that sorts the data based on users input. By price high to low for example it could also be year or a number of other values. However the user is only able to sort by one value at a time. Your question has me thinking maybe I could apply a secondary `$sort` to inventoryProducts and skip creating `salesInventoryProducts` all together.